# window.CavalryLogger error in Facebook App running in Facebook Page Tab

Tags: facebook, tabs

I have applications which are displayed as tabs in Facebook pages which have been working fine.  They suddenly started displaying this output in the tab:

/*1336720089,176820405*/

```
if (window.CavalryLogger) { CavalryLogger.start_js(["EgxV3"]); }

__d("UFIUpdate",
```

Any ideas what is going on???

Here is a link to one of them: http://www.facebook.com/TweakShoes/app_132692060112327

Comment: some users, but not all (or even myself) have started seeing this in our app, too

Comment: The problem went away. I am assuming something was wrong with the Facebook js lib? If anyone, however, could provide insight into how to avoid the problem, or if they have similar experience, that would be helpful.

Comment: it is for non-secure browsing users. confirmed this. nothing to do with javascript. I get the error with just a blank html page as the page tab URL. works fine if https is present.

Comment: disable the picture access and everything was better. regards

Answer (score 4):

A temporary solution is to add https:// to facebook itself. This doesn't solve the problem, but it'll allow you to see your page on a per client basis.

The best fix in the longer term until facebook fixes this issue is to go to your account settings > Security > Enable secure browsing. This will enforce HTTPS wherever it can and should resolve the issue for a lot of pages you're trying to access.

Good Luck!

Comment: Does that mean that everyone who is using the application will need to make these changes? Most users wouldn't have a clue how to do this. Can you simply do a redirect on your applications iFrame to force https? (if they come in via http)

Answer (score 1):

After encountering this issue yesterday, I tracked it down to an apparent conflict with the JS log wrapper included as part of HTML5 Boilerplate's script.js file. In particular, the "make it safe to use console.log always" snippet. After commenting it out, the FB lib error went away and my app displayed properly.

I didn't dig into what the conflict was, but here is the snippet. If you use something similar on your page, then it may be worth investigating.

```
/* make it safe to use console.log always */
(function(b){function c(){}for(var d="assert,count,debug,dir,dirxml,error,exception,group,groupCollapsed,groupEnd,info,log,timeStamp,profile,profileEnd,time,timeEnd,trace,warn".split(","),a;a=d.pop();){b[a]=b[a]||c}})((function(){try
{console.log();return window.console;}catch(err){return window.console={};}})());
```

It's probably not a coincidence that FB's own logger bugs out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook [has opened a bug for this issue](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/362855400443900) and recently triaged it to medium priority - no word on when it will be addressed.